# How to center world map using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, openstreetmap

I am trying to display the full map using leaflet.
[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GLQYzy)

I am trying to achieve the following via leaflet:

[image]

I thought using `mymap.fitWorld()` would achieve the effect but it is not.

Comment: You might want to use `L.CRS.EPSG4326` as the map's CRS, and then load that blue marble image as a `L.ImageOverlay`

Comment: Hi @user3525290. Did you check my answer. Did it solve your issue?

Comment: @kboul sort of.  I might go a different routne.  https://www.n2yo.com/ Trying to track satellite like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide minZoom and maxZoom levels to be 1 like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 1,
 });
```

and then define setView as follows:

```
map.setView([0, 0], 0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title>Zoom Levels Tutorial - Leaflet</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>


 <style>
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
  }
 </style>

 
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

 var map = L.map('map', {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 1,
 });

 var cartodbAttribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>';

 var positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', ).addTo(map);


 map.setView([0, 0], 0);
</script>



</body>
</html>
```